# Windows Phone photo size

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have both a CameraCaptureTask and a PhotoChooserTask in my app where you can either take or load a photo.  The end goal of all of this is to finally send it to an Azure Web API.

The photo that I get back from both of these tasks is very large (about 4mb) and about 3000x2000 pixels in dimensions.

Is there a way to get a much smaller version of the picture?  This is how I handle the chooser;

```
    public void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            var bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
            ...
```

Is there a way to load a smaller 'thumbnail' version or do I have to manipulate the image and resize it?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: You have to manually resize it.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more detail and explanation? Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WriteableBitmap bmpWritable = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Extensions.SaveJpeg(bmpWritable, ms, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 100);
```

I would suggest you resize it proportionally.
Hope this helps.

And also, You need not to have two separate tasks for taking image from Camera and from gallery. For `PhotoChooserTask` itself, you can set `ShowCamera` attribute to true. This will display a camera button when in ApplicationBar when you open gallery

Comment: Hi - thanks for the code demo.  I ended up using WriteableBitmap.Resize(), but this pointed me in the right direction.